# Print up to (and including) the nth occurence of a pattern in a line

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression, pcregrep

Let's say I have multiple lines ***similar*** to below in a file.

```
Turbo is a cat. cats are good. cats are not dog.
Coco is a black cat. cats are furry. cats are not dog.
```

now, if want to `grep` all the `^.*cat` but want to specially mention to capture till first (or nth) occurrence of the word `cat`.
Desired Output:

```
Turbo is a cat
Coco is a black cat
*blah is a so and so cat*
```

How can I `grep` it?

PS: I would love to have an answer using `grep` (or its other variants) only.

PS: I don't want to grep `^.*cat.` and then do any operation  to remove the  **"."**  . I want a generic answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **POSIX grep**, you can only choose between printing the whole line, or not printing the line content at all. If you want to transform the line, you need to use another tool such as sed or awk. To print up to the first occurrence of `cat`:

```
sed -n 's/cat.*/cat/'
awk 'sub(/cat.*/,"")'
```

Printing up to the *N*th occurrence is more complicated.

```
sed -n 's/cat/&\
/3; T; P'
awk 'gsub(/cat/,"&\n") >= 3 {split($0, a, "\n"); printf "%s%s%s\n", a[1], a[2], a[3]}'
```

With **GNU grep**, you can use the `-o` option to print only the matched part of the line. Use the `-P` option to activate Perl syntax, so that [non-greedy quantifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers) are available.

```
grep -P -o '^(.*?cat){1}'
```

Replace the number in braces by the number *n* of the last occurrence of `cat` to be printed.

While it's possible to express the same thing with extended regular expressions (`-E`), this requires a complex regexp, whose size is exponential in the size of the part to count (`cat` here).

Answer (score 1):

`grep` only selects lines based on the regular expression specified and prints them.

I think you are forced to pipe the output lines and use an additional command to do the job.

Usually you would use `sed` or `awk` to do the job without `grep`, because they can both select lines and replace strings.

There is a solution below using `awk`:

```
awk -v word=cat -v n=2 'BEGIN {wordlength=length(word);} {line=$0;outputline="";position=index(line,word);for (i=1;position>0 && i<=n; i++) { outputline=outputline substr(line,1,position+wordlength-1);line=substr(line,position+wordlength);position=index(line,word);  } if (i!=1) {print outputline;}}'
```

You should set `word` to the string to search and the `n` to the number of occurrences wanted.

The test:

```
$ awk -v word=cat -v n=2 'BEGIN {wordlength=length(word);} {line=$0;outputline="";position=index(line,word);for (i=1;position>0 && i<=n; i++) { outputline=outputline substr(line,1,position+wordlength-1);line=substr(line,position+wordlength);position=index(line,word);  } if (i!=1) {print outputline;}}' file
Turbo is a cat. cat
Coco is a black cat. cat
```

Comment: So, regular expression cannot help selecting till nth pattern?
Can't we have something similar to Eelvex's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422949/how-to-find-the-3rd-occurrence-of-a-pattern-on-a-line

Comment: @KrishnaGupta The link is showing a solution with regular expression extension with `perl`. I am not familiar with it. The answer had been updated with a `awk` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `sed` solution (e.g. print up to and including the 2nd occurrence; replace `2` with your no.):

```
sed -n 's/cat/&\
/2
t print
d
:print
P' infile
```

This disables autoprinting via `-n` and attempts to replace the 2nd occurrence of `cat` with `cat`+ a newline character. If the substitution is successful it branches to `:print` and `P`rints up to the newline, otherwise the line is `d`eleted.

---

With `gnu sed` you could write it as a one liner (e.g. print up to and including the 5th occurrence):

```
sed -n 's/cat/&\n/5;tt;d;:t;P' infile
```

Comment: Note that my answer assumes you don't want to print lines with less than _N_ occurrences. It can be easily modified to print those lines too.